# Problem in understanding a theorem in A book of abstract algebra - Charles C Pinter (Chapter 31)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In the discussion below we are assuming that $F$ is a field of characterisc $0$.

Let $K$ and $K'$ be finite extensions of the field $F$ and $K$ and $K'$ have a commom extension $E$. If $h:K \rightarrow K'$ is a isomorphism such that $h(x) =x$ for every $x$ in $F$ and $K$ is the root field of some polynomial $a(x)$ over $F$ then $h$ maps elements of $K$ to elements of $K$.

The problem begins when Pinter states the following theorem.

Theorem: Let $K$ and $K'$ be finite extensions of $F$. Assume $K$ is the root field of some polynomial over $F$. If $h: K\rightarrow K'$ is a isomorphism which fixes $F$, then $K = K'$.

Proof: We know that $K$ and $K'$ are simple extensions of $F$, say $K=F(a)$ and $K'=F(b)$. Then $E=F(a,b)$ is a commom extension of $K$ and $K'$. By the comments preeceding this theorem, $h$ maps every element of $K$ to an element of $K'$; hence $K' \subseteq K$. Since the same argument may be carried out for $h^{-1}$, we also have $K \subseteq K'$. QED

I can understand the reason why $K' \subseteq K$, but I don't know how to proceed to prove the other inclusion ( $K \subseteq K'$), if someone can help me understand this theorem, I will really appreciate. For futher details, this situation can be found on chapter 31 page 316 of the second edtion of Pinter's book.

Comment: If $h$ is an isomorphism from $K$ to $K'$, then $h^{-1}$ is an ismorphism from $K'$ to $K$, and if $h$ fixes $F$, then $h^{-1}$ also fixes $F$.

Comment: But to show that $K' \subseteq K$ we use that $range(h) =  K'$ and that $h$ maps every element from $K$ to elements of $K$, so $K' \subseteq K$. With $h^{-1}$ we don't have the same situation because $K'$ is not necessarily a root of field of $F$.

Comment: An isimorphism takes roots to roots, so based on that, if $K$ is a root field of some polynomial over $F$, then so is $K'$.

Comment: Another way to look at it is, if $K'=F(b)$, and $[K':F]=m$, then $b$ has degree $m$ over $F$. But then $h^{-1}(b)$ also has degree $m$ over $F$, so $[K:F]\ge m$. Hence, since you already have $K\subseteq K'$, it follows that $K=K'$.

Comment: Oh, you are right, thank you!